# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 ipa upload wink error

Tags: ipa, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

When attempting to upload a new ipa to MobileFirst, in Chrome or Firefox, the application center returns an error.  When I look at the WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.0 server logs, I see the following errors:

> [7/10/15 11:57:32:177 EDT] 000000c9
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ResourceRegistry    I The
>   system cannot find any method in the
>   com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService class that supports GET.
>   Verify that a method exists.
>
> [7/10/15 11:57:32:185 EDT] 000000c9
>   org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             I The
>   following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain:
>   WebApplicationException (405) with message 'null' while processing GET
>   request sent to
>   http://mobile.ps.com/applicationcenter/service/desktop/upload/filetype/ipa

Some searches have turned up suggestions about the Java version being 1.8 and thus not supported, but 1.8 is not installed.  The system is using the 1.7 Java that comes with Liberty.  I tried applying the most recent MobileFirst ifix, but it did not change anything.

Comment: Don't confuse MobileFirst Server with Application Center - two completely and totally different servers.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can say that the applicationcenter.war running on the Liberty server is somehow not part of the MobileFirst server.  MF is just a set of war files configured on a app server.  In my case, they are all installed on the same Liberty instance.  How does this makes any difference to the original question?

Comment: MobileFirst Server does not serve .ipa files; you upload your .ipa file to the Application Center server, not MobileFirst Server. Two different servers, two different sets of war and jar files. They may sit on the same application server, but they are not one and the same. I am writing this because you are using both interchangeably in your explanation of the problem you're facing, which is confusing and wrong, that's why.

Comment: In addition, you should not use MFP 7.0 on top of Liberty 8.5.5.0, it is not recommended and may cause issues down the road. You should upgrade to 8.5.5.4 or .5.

Comment: And a final clarification: IBM MobileFirst Platform Application Center is an offering of said MFP. It is meant to act as an independent app store for your enterprise apps. The ipa files may either native or hybrid (and based on MFPF), but that's it. It's not related to MobileFirst Platform Foundation Server. I hope this is now clearer for you.

Comment: I was mistaken.. the system has Liberty 8.5.5.4.  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: Provide the full messages.log

Comment: Sadly, that is the full message.log, unless you want to see the entire server startup.  Adding trace didn't add any extra messages either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to have http enabled.  You can't redirect from http to https.  The upload service uses a POST request.  POST request data is not preserved when redirecting.  Thus the 405 message as the request is re-attempted as a GET.